# changing the float of an image with Jquery for each item

Tags: jquery, foreach

I am building a certain page with an image on one side and some text on the other.
I am willing to change the image "float" from right to left for every item (for each) I know how to that that with Java but Im pretty new to Jquery.
I've tried to find something similar on stack but didnt find anything, if You could help Me with that toggle class for each item (add and remove class), what I mean is toggle it from 1st item and display container 1 with picture on the left, container 2 with picture on the right etc.

```
 <article class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 thumbnail-style thumbnail-icon-item text-left ">

                   <div class="thumbnail icon-left row">

                      <div class="col-md-2">

                          <div class="img-con">
                            <img class="img-middle" src="images/Services/1.png" alt="">
                            </div>

                      </div>

                     <div class="col-md-10">
                     <div class="caption cap-no-top-mar">
                       <h4>Finacial Planning</h4>
                       <p>
                        Quisque pulvinar libero dolor, quis bibendum eros euismod sit amet. Proin dapibus id diam at
                       </p>
                        <!-- <a class="learn-more" href="services-detail.html"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Learn More

                        </a> -->
                     </div>
                    </div>

                   </div>
                   <div class="line"></div>

              </article><!-- End article -->
              <article class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 thumbnail-style thumbnail-icon-item text-left ">

                   <div class="thumbnail icon-left">

                      <div class="col-md-2">
                       <div class="img-con">
                       <img class="img-icon-thumbnail img-middle" src="images/Services/2.png" alt="">
                       </div>
                       </div>

                     <div class="col-md-10">
                     <div class="caption cap-no-top-mar">
                       <h4>Investments Management</h4>
                       <p>
                        Quisque pulvinar libero dolor, quis bibendum eros euismod sit amet. Proin dapibus id diam at
                       </p>
                       <!-- <a class="learn-more" href="services-detail.html"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Learn More

                        </a> -->
                     </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="line"></div>
              </article><!-- End article -->
```

Thats the containers, I've tried some stuff but nothing helped because I lack some knowledge.

Heres a small js fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/subz3r0/3ywnm5t3/

Thanks in advance and have a wonderful day.

Comment: So your question is?

Comment: Thanks for the super fast reply, I dont know how to toggle the class for each element (add for 1st element and remove from second and so on), I've tried to put on the img container the float class and remove it but failed

Comment: You want a [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function?

Comment: I don't understand what op want ?

Comment: I think he wants to toggle a class which will change the float of the element. Not sure

Comment: I want the image containers float side to change from left to right for each item I add, 1st container with image on the right side second on the left 3rd on the right 4th on the left and so on

Comment: But where is the images in your code example. We need something to work with if you want us to help you

Comment: Need small workable snippet to help you.

Comment: yea sorry, the image is in col-md-2 in each article, I've added a class f-left in col-md-2 div to change the bootstrap float from left to right and it didnt help, wait, ill add a snippet, and thank You all for fast response!

Comment: `$('article:even').css('float','right'); $('article:odd').css('float','left');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nt-child` property of css

```
article:nth-child(odd) .thumbnail {
   float: right;
}
article:nth-child(even) .thumbnail {
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: I thank You very much kind sir!!! It helped alot article:nth-child(odd) .col-md-2.art {
    float: right;
 }
 article:nth-child(even) .col-md-2.art {
    float: left;
 }